# How to use this angular factory in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Factory:

```
factory('cordovaReady', function () {
    return function (fn) {

        var queue = [];

        var impl = function () {
            queue.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        };

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
            queue.forEach(function (args) {
                fn.apply(this, args);
            });
            impl = fn;
        }, false);

        return function () {
            return impl.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    };
})
```

I used this factory in another factory like this:

```
return {
    getCurrentPosition: cordovaReady(function (onSuccess, onError, options) {
        //
    }
}
```

The cordovaReady factory will execute the passed callback when the deviceReady event was fired. My question is how do I use it in controller?

I tried with just

```
.controller( 'HomeCtrl', function HomeController($scope, cordovaReady) {   
  cordovaReady(function(){
        //do stuff
  });   
});
```

But it did not work. No console errors. Any ideas?

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: @maxdec just updated my question

Comment: "didn't work" ?  Are there any console error messages, did you try tracing execution using  devtools/firebug?  Could it be a minification issue, since you aren't using the minification friendly form of the controller definition?

Comment: Are both controller and your service in the same module (and if not does one declare dependency to another?). Do you minify your JS code?

Comment: @lpiepiora same module, no minification

Comment: How about this: `cordovaReady()(function(){ //do stuff });` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by wrapping the factor like this

```
.factory('aUseCase', function ($q, $rootScope, cordovaReady) {
    return {
        doSomething: cordovaReady(function () {
            //do stuff
        })
    };
})
```

Answer (score 2):

better version of @artworkad :

```
.factory('aUseCase', ['$q', '$rootScope', 'cordovaReady', function ($q, $rootScope, cordovaReady) {
    return {
        doSomething: cordovaReady(function () {
            //do stuff
        })
    };
}])
```

Don't forget to inject dependencies explicitly otherwise you will have problem when minifying this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your dependency is being injected into your controller?

```
var MyController = function($scope, cordovaReady) {
  ...
}
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'cordovaReady'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller you need to declare a function to use cordovaReady

```
myApp.controller("salaryCalculatorCtr", ['$scope', 'cordovaReady'
, function ($scope, cordovaReady) {

    var initApp= cordovaReady(function () {

       //do something
    });
    initApp();
}]);
```